# Why if [ -d "dir/proc" ] true when ls "dir" gives total 0 (might be chroot / proc related)?

Tags: bash, mount, chroot

I was making liveUSB iso file, doing many mounts, plus `chroot script` having `mount -t proc proc /proc` in the script (`chroot` is a new thing for me, I noticed the issue when I was ding some "cleaning" and script run with chroot was not running any more). And now have IMO very strange situation, how is it possible for system to behave in such a way?

```
$ if [ -d "newdir/proc" ]; then echo 1;fi
1
$ if [ -d "newdir/pro" ]; then echo 1;fi
$ sudo ls -al "newdir"
total 0
```

The issue also is that `umount newdir` outputs "target is busy". `findmnt | grep proc` no longer shows "newdir/proc" line.

Added 1:

```
$ sudo ls -al "newdir/media/root/usb" # another mount
total 0
$ sudo ls -al "newdir/media/root"
total 0
$ sudo ls -al "newdir/media"
total 0
```

If it could make a difference, `newdir` is in `tmpfs` system.

Added 2:
After suggestion from the answer by @Bart I ran `lsof` and realised I had another terminal where I did `chroot newdir` to see IIRC results of the script. Now I exited that chroot, `lsof | grep nwdir` no longer outputs list if those bash commands, only warnings about `fuse.gvfsd-fuse` and `fuse /run/user/1000/doc`. Still the same for:

```
$ sudo ls -al "newdir/media/root"
total 0
```

However after that I was able to do w/out errors in output `umount newdir` and after that `sudo ls -al "newdir/media/root"`gave `no such file`.

**P.S.** the cause of the unexpected behavior was identified with help here: not closed terminal with chroot. However, I've read how to access files using handles of open processes, but here "ghosting" evidenced itself for ordinary way to run `ls`, **I still hope I will see explanation why/how it worked that way.**

Comment: what does `ls -ld /path/to/newdir` say about permissions?

Answer (score 3):

The `procfs` is not even a real filesystem, rather a representation of the contents of memory and the currently running processes. What you are seeing, indicates that some processes created their files in side the chroot mounted `proc`, but did not exit and still use file references in that directory.

`lsof | grep /newdir/proc` should show you what processes still use unexisting location.

What you want is probably to bind mount it to a location inside the chroot:

```
mkdir -m 0555 newdir/proc
mount --bind /proc newdir/proc
```

and not `mount -t`.

Comment: please see "added 1" - noted other mounts also became "ghost" folders, not only `proc`. How does it affect your answer?

Comment: I'd check all the directories that you list with lsof, and since you probably ran chroot, it might not have exited in full, still showing references to the directories that were mounted in the chroot

Comment: see Added 2. Your guess that I left some `chroot` was correct. Why has it resulted in such strange (IMO) results for `ls`?

Comment: As for `mount --bind /proc newdir/proc`, I did `ps` and `mount`, got error and suggestion to run  `mount -t proc proc /proc`. After that command some errors disappeared. What would be different with `--bind`?

Comment: is it possible to create files inside `procfs`?

Comment: @ilkkachu [I don't think so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681383/how-can-i-source-environment-changes-system-wide/681385#comment1287607_681385).